# SUM & Average of TIME in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, average

```
Talktime
01:02:55
00:53:59
01:16:59
01:13:30
```

For the above example how can we apply SUM and AVERAGE of time in JQUERY DATATABLES

```
    jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sumTime()', function ( ) {
return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {

    var timeRegexp = /^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/

    var matches = a.match(timeRegexp);
    if (matches) {
        var hh = matches[1], mm = matches[2], ss = matches[3];
        var intervalAsSeconds = hh * 24 + mm * 60 + ss;
        return b + intervalAsSeconds;
    }

    return a + b;
}, 0 );
} );
```

The above code is for SUM and is'nt working

Comment: @mmushtaq I have edited the question for the current code for SUM

Comment: @davidkonrad I haven't down voted for it.

Comment: @mmushtaq assumed per your comment ;) It is OK, I just notice more and more auto downvoting not so well written questions, and then OP improves their questions downvoters forget to acknowledge - in the end we end up with a lot of good questions having negative score, and a lot of frustrated users ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below worked for me

SUM of time:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sumTime()', function () {
  var data = this.flatten();
  var pageTotal_Duration = data.reduce( function ( a, b ) {
       return moment.duration(a).asMilliseconds() + moment.duration(b).asMilliseconds()
  }, 0);

   return moment.utc(pageTotal_Duration).format("HH:mm:ss");
});
```

AVERAGE of time:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'averageTime()', function () {
   var data = this.flatten();
   var pageTotal_DurationA = data.reduce( function ( a, b ) {
       return moment.duration(a).asMilliseconds() + moment.duration(b).asMilliseconds()
   }, 0);

   return moment.utc(pageTotal_DurationA/data.length).format("HH:mm:ss");
});
```